# i cant C++ run vscode

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code, mingw-w64, winmain

I need help.

I installed Visual Studio Code, then I installed the latest version of MingW for C++ programming.

When I try to  run the program, I got an error: `"cc1plus is not detected"`.
I tried to fix it on my own by putting the directory in the system environment variables.

Then I received another error:
`main': C:/_/M/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to WinMain' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status PS C:\Users\angel\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio Code\PRogramming WorkSpace\C++>`

I don't understand what this error means.
I hope someone can help me solve this problem.

My Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;
  
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
PS C:\Users\angel\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio Code\PRogramming WorkSpace> cd "c:\Users\angel\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio Code\PRogramming WorkSpace\C++\" ; if ($?) { g++ test.cpp -o test } ; if ($?) { .\test }

C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o): in function `main':
C:/_/M/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
PS C:\Users\angel\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio Code\PRogramming WorkSpace\C++>
```

Comment: we now have 2 `WinMain` questions in 1 day, will we break a record

Comment: Sadly due to distribution fragmentation, *the latest version of MingW* doesn't convey as much information as you might like. Fortunately the *msys64* on one of the paths strongly suggests which distribution (a good, up-to-date one) is in use.